# How add a thickness to a surfacic Mesh?

Tags: 3d, volume, mesh

I'm seeking for a method to add a thickness to a surfacic mesh which is in 3D.
The aim is to start with vertex and edges I already have and add vertex and edges in order to obtain a volumic mesh in 3D with tetrahedra.
Maybe this is possible with some Poisson disk or Best candidate algorithm, to find the new vertice?

Do anyone know a method or a software (open source if possible) to do that?

ymmx

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to just duplicate the mesh (vertices+triangles), offset the new vertices back by a fixed distance along vertex normals (vertex normal = normalized average of normals of triangles that share it), and flip the vertex order in the new triangles. Then go over all open edges in the original mesh and close them by connecting to their peers in the new mesh with 2 new triangles. Of course, if the original mesh has some high-frequency details, the new parts may create overlaps, so depending on what you need it for, this might require some more work.